# React Native build failed in android, @react-native-community/cli-platform-android /native_modules.gradle' line: 130

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, gradle

I've upgraded my ReactNative project from **0.59 to 0.61.2** iOS is building fine but in android i'm facing the issue in **@react-native-community/cli-platform-android** module.

My **settings.gradle** file

```
apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)
```

My **build.gradle** file

```
apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

I get the following error while building the app.

```
> Task :app:generatePackageList FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/yashwanth_c/Documents/projects/MobileApp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android
/native_modules.gradle' line: 130

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:generatePackageList'.
> ReactNativeModules$_generatePackagesFile_closure3

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 5m 21s
4 actionable tasks: 4 executed
```

As always i've cleaned the cache and deleted the node_module folder, tried many times but no luck. Also googled for more than a week but still not able to find a fix, any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 35):

I had same issues then i tried below command. it's worked for me.
It's mean, mannually install the android cli package.

```
npm i @react-native-community/cli-platform-android
```

If anyone known another solution kindly share here.

Comment: didn't expect it to work, but it did.

Comment: This solution resolved that particular build issue. But, as usual, resolving one uncovers the next... ;-\
I used `yarn add @react-native-community/cli-platform-android` instead.

Comment: Sometimes the error may occur with incompatible subsequent dependencies. To resolve that I used - `npm i @react-native-community/cli-platform-android --force`

Answer (score 15):

I was facing the same issue in React Native 0.61.0. I have tried the below solution:-

1. Closed the Android studio.
2. cd android
3. `./gradlew --stop (in MacOS)`
4. `./gradlew cleanBuildCache (in MacOS)`

For Window:-

1. `gradlew --stop`
2. `gradlew cleanBuildCache`

Check below linking for more reference https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/issues/591

Comment: I can confirm that this helped with RN 0.62.2 when react-native run-android failed in _generatePackagesFile_closure3.

Comment: Helped on RN 0.63.3, another last resort fixer I use is: `cd android ; rm -rf app/build; ./gradlew --stop; ./gradlew clean; ./gradlew cleanBuildCache; cd ../; react-native run-android`

Answer (score 12):

I'm working in a monorepo. The file exists, but it was in my **project** root's `node_modules/@react-native-community` NOT the package `node_modules`.

To fix this, I updated the paths

`/android/settings.gradle : Line 2`

```
apply from: file("../../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)
```

`/android/app/build.gradle : Line 225`

```
apply from: file("../../../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

Comment: This is pretty much guaranteed to happen if you are moving to a monorepo.

Answer (score 6):

I have also face the same kind of problem. I don't know but for some reason, in the `node_modules` `cli-platform-android` package folder was not showing.

Then I follow these steps, to solve the issue.

```
-> Remove `node_modules` folder
-> Remove `package-lock.json` file
-> Then install all the package again using `npm install`
-> Then `Rebuild the project in android studio`. That is how my issue was solved.
```

Answer (score 6):

Delete "node_modules", "packagelock.json" folders and then

```
yarn add @react-native-community/cli-platform-android@3.0.3
cd android && gradlew clean
```

Comment: not work for me

Answer (score 3):

If your react-native app fails to install on android emulator,

try going to

```
gradle-wrapper.propeties
```

and update

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip
```

Make sure that gradle is updated to the stable and lastest version according to what it suits

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was using PNPM, so I had to manually install `@react-native-community/cli-platform-android`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem because I switched branches. You can try removing these things and reinstalling the dependencies to solve the problem.

delelte these:

> android\build
>
> android\app\build
>
> node_modules
>
> **yarn.lock**
>
> **package.lock.json**

re-execute yarn

```
yarn install
yarn android
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try installing packages using yarn or npm install?
i was facing the same issue then I realized I did not install all the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it is because the package name has move from `AndroidManifest.xml` to `build.gradle`.  Solved it by adding the package name back to `AndroidManifest.xml`

Answer (score 0):

### For Monorepo

In my case I am working on Monorepo with 3 different apps using single code base.

---

#### One

```js
//  packages/myapp/android/app/build.gradle:78

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "packages/myapp/index.js",
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
    cliPath: "../../node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js",
]

// Update with extra '../' to point to the root `node_modules`
apply from: "../../../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just go to your `MainActivity.java` file located on
`C:\...path...\..\android\app\src\main\java\com\appname\MainActivity.java`

just remove any imports above `package com.yourappname;` and put them below it as below

```
package com.driverapp; //nothing above of this line that says package com.xxx

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

i was using `pnpm` package manager and it was not downloading `@react-native-community` packages including `cli-platform-android`.

i used `yarn` in it took care of it.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue when transitioning from Windows to macOS and had trouble running my React Native project. The root cause was related to executable permissions on the Gradle file. To resolve this issue, follow these steps:

1. Open your terminal and navigate to your project's root directory:

   ```bash
   cd android
   ```

   This command will take you to the 'android' folder within your project.
2. Grant execute permissions to the Gradle script using either of the following commands:

   ```bash
   chmod +x ./gradlew
   ```

   or

   ```bash
   chmod +x gradlew
   ```
3. Return to the project's root directory:

   ```bash
   cd ..
   ```
4. Try running your project again.

These steps should help you resolve any permission issues when running your project on macOS. It's a common issue when transitioning from Windows, and granting execute permissions to the Gradle script is the key to solving it.

Answer (score 0):

i was facing same issue what helps me is delete "node_modules" install again "node_modules" using this cmd : npm i then go to android_studio go to Build -> Clean Project